# How to translate sql to hibernate criteria query

Tags: hibernate, criteria

How do i translate this pseudo-query into a hibernate criteria query?

Given itemID=123, item table has a foreign key reference to category table (catgeoryId), i want to return category coresp to the item with id 123...

select cats.category from Item as item
inner join category as cats
where item.id = itemID

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do a Criteria? Given that you know the id, you can just load your Item and inspect it's Category field.

The goal of Hibernate is to make database programming simpler for OOP programmers, not more convoluted.

Comment: Good point. I need the category object instead of the item because i need to extract some of its properties. Is it not better to write a query that returns the category object instead of the item object? rather than needing to inspect the category when i dont actually need the actual item?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about situations that make Hibernate to generate 1+1 selects. Between maintaining the clarity of code and avoiding 1+n selects you will have plenty to do in your application.

Comment: It all depends on how complex the base Entity is. There's no reason to fetch the base entity if all the user needs is the category. Taking the approach of asking Hibernate to only give you what you really need is generally the safest in the long run. That said, I agree Criteria is not the best approach for this specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Criteria isn't the best match for this particular need. Criteria are most useful when you're building dynamic queries, in my experience.

If I understand your domain correctly, this is pretty simply expressed in HQL:

```
select item.category from Item item where item.id = :itemId
```